# Finding the position vector of a particle in a rotating frame

Tags: rotational-dynamics, vectors, angular-velocity

Consider a vector $\mathbf{u}$ which is fixed in a rotating frame. In a time $\delta t$ it rotates through an angle $\delta\theta$ about $\mathbf{n}$. i.e. it moves to

\begin{align}
\mathbf{u}+\delta\mathbf{u}&=\mathbf{u}\cos{\delta\theta}+(\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{n})\mathbf{n}(1-\cos{\delta\theta})-\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{n}\sin\delta\theta\\
&=\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{n}\times\mathbf{u}\delta\theta+O\left(\delta\theta^2\right)
\end{align}

Now i'm quite confused on how the first equality is found and then how it simplifies to the second equality. Could anyone shine some light on these?

Comment: Have you read through this yet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_reference_frame

Comment: I have read through "relation between positions in the two frames" but it doesn't really help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equality is shown e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Conversion_from_and_to_axis-angle). Basically, the axis of rotation of a rotation given by a rotation matrix is along the eigenvector to the eigenvalue $1$ (as it remains unchanged). The rotation angle can then be determined by calculating the angle between a vector orthogonal to the axis of rotation and its rotated counterpart. If we know both the angle and the axis of rotation, we can write the rotation according to your first equality because of [Rodrigues rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula), which I am not going to prove here because you will find that easily in linear algebra books even if wikipedia was ever to stop showing it.

The second equality comes by expanding the $\sin$ and $\cos$ to linear order, i.e., $\sin x = x + O(x^3)$ and $\cos x = 1 + O(x^2)$, and then using the skew-symmetry of the cross product.